# How can I loop through images from a folder in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can manually enter the image names in a list at the moment. I would like to just assign a folder so that it can loop through the images from that folder.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

pics = ["a5.png", "a6.png"]
photos = [tk.PhotoImage(file=x) for x in pics]
label = tk.Label()
label.photos = photos
label.counter = 0
def changeimage():
    label['image'] = label.photos[label.counter%len(label.photos)]
    label.after(3000, changeimage)
    label.counter += 1
label.pack()
changeimage()

root.mainloop()
```

tried few methods including:

```
import random, os
rand_image = random.choice([
    x for x in os.listdir(path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
])
```

I was not able to connect the dots. Not sure where I'm wrong.

Thank you! Below code worked

```
pics = glob.glob("picturefolder/*.png")
```

Comment: You probably want `pics = glob.glob("picturefolder/*.png")`. Not sure about that random part, though. Do you want to loop them in random order?

Comment: What is the problem with the `random.choice` code?  If it didn't work, please explain.

Comment: When I use the random.choice code I get an error. 
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "a7.png": no such file or directory.
I have a7.png in the folder. I have path set as --> path = "./yoga_Images/"

Comment: pics = glob.glob("picturefolder/*.png") worked! Thank you :)

Comment: @Advik that means your python script is placed one folder behind the png file right?

Answer (score 0):

I modified pics a little.

```
path = os.getcwd() # You can specifiy this path of images; The current path is the same directory of your python script.
pics = [os.path.join(path, x) for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x)) and x.endswith('.png')]
photos = [tk.PhotoImage(file=x) for x in pics]
```